# How can I extract the strike price from a Quantlib option object?

Tags: programming, quantlib

I am trying to write a Python function that performs some calculations using a list of Quantlib options, and I would like to pass only that list without other information. In particular, the strike of each option is embedded there somewhere, but I am finding it hard to extract. Here is a toy example of an instance (extracted from one of Luigi Ballabio's excellent tutorial notebooks):

```
from QuantLib import *
maturity_date = Date(15, 1, 2016)
spot_price = 127.62
strike_price = 130
volatility = 0.20 # the historical vols for a year
dividend_rate =  0.0163
option_type = Option.Call

risk_free_rate = 0.001
day_count = Actual365Fixed()
calendar = UnitedStates()

calculation_date = Date(8, 5, 2015)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

payoff = PlainVanillaPayoff(option_type, strike_price)
exercise = EuropeanExercise(maturity_date)
european_option = VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)
```

Now I would like to use something like `european_option.strike`. That doesn't work, of course. Can someone offer a simple solution? (TIA.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very old question now, but here it is for reference in case someone stumbles upon it: the object returned by `european_option.payoff()` has type `ql.Payoff` (i.e., the base class for payoffs) and doesn't have the `strike` method.  Now, Python doesn't do casts like C++, but for some objects we export functions that perform the underlying C++ cast and return the object with the correct derived type.  This is one such case, and one can write:

```
ql.as_plain_vanilla_payoff(european_option.payoff()).strike()
```

to downcast the payoff and then retrieve the strike.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the strike from the PlainVanillaPayoff object which is `payoff` in your example.

`payoff.strike()` returns `130.0` for me.

Comment: Thanks, but ```option.payoff.strike()``` does not work. I want to submit ```option``` as an argument to a function, and extract the strike from ```option``` inside the function. I do not want to submit additional arguments (like ```payoff```).

Comment: There is no `option.payoff.strike()`. Your variable is named `payoff`.  You named it as such. You could rename it to `option` and then `option.strike()` would work.  Sorry if I am misunderstanding your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry: I should have said ```european_option.payoff.strike()``` does not work. I would like my function to derive the strike from ```european_option```.